# select post where id is not get_the_ID()

Tags: wordpress

This array select a random post.

i want to select a post, that id is not active post id (in single page)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
);
```

Comment: `'post__not_in' => [get_queried_object_id()],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters for reference to the parameters you can use within $args.

You will need to add:

```
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
```

To your $args array.

Note: you may need to declare `global $post;` before your query so that $post->ID is valid.

Comment: Great stuff :) glad to have been of help, if you could mark this as the answer that would be fab.